# Swiss Tournament. Team confrontation multiple rounds without repeat and ordered

Tags: php, tournament

I try to make a tournament based on Swiss method.
I have for example 12 teams, and in each round, every team has points (0 to 100) and wins, loses or draws.
I want to find which teams play against each other, with these conditions:

- Ordered by wins, draws, and points.
- Not to be played previously.

In each round, I got foreach team the possible teams to play against in an array like this: (The key indicates the team id, and the values indicate ll possible teams to play separated by ",")

```
[2] => 4,11,6,10,3,8,7,12,
[5] => 4,11,9,10,3,8,1,12,
[4] => 2,5,6,10,8,7,12,
[11] => 5,9,10,3,8,7,
[9] => 5,11,6,3,8,7,12,
[6] => 2,4,9,10,3,7,12,
[10] => 2,5,4,11,6,8,7,12,
[3] => 5,11,9,6,8,7,
[8] => 2,5,4,11,9,10,3,1,12,
[7] => 2,4,11,9,6,10,3,1,12,
[1] => 5,4,11,9,6,3,8,7,
[12] => 2,5,4,9,6,10,8,7,
```

First I have all teams played before in a array: (key indicates team id)

```
Array (
    [1] => 2,10,12,
    [2] => 1,9,5,
    [3] => 4,12,10,
    [4] => 3,11,9,
    [5] => 6,7,2,
    [6] => 5,8,11,
    [7] => 8,5,8,
    [8] => 7,6,7,
    [9] => 10,2,4,
    [10] => 9,1,3,
    [11] => 12,4,6,
    [12] => 11,3,1, )
```

Then, I get all teams ordered by wins, loses and points in a array: (Keys indicates also team id)

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 10
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 8
    [10] => 7
    [11] => 1
    [12] => 12
)
```

Finaly I try to find the possible match against two teams.

```
$checks = array();
$pairs = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($list); $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= count($list); $j++) {
        if(strpos($plays[$list[$i]], $list[$j]) !== false || $list[$i] == $list[$j] ) {
        }else{
            if(!in_array($list[$i],$checks) && !in_array($list[$j],$checks)){
                $pairs[] = $list[$i].",".$list[$j];
                $checks[] = $list[$i];
                $checks[] = $list[$j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finaly I print the array "$pairs". It shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2,4
    [1] => 5,11
    [2] => 9,6
    [3] => 10,8
    [4] => 3,7
)
```

Thats not correct because the team_id 1 and team_id 12 can not play in this round because the played before:

I don't know how to solve this.

Thanks again!

Comment: _How I find which teams play against in next round?_ By writting some code. Sorry, that's harsh, but that's how StackOverflow works.

Comment: What did you try ? Post a sample of code please.

Comment: Welcome Anna. Ok. Show us what you have worked out so far

Comment: Sorry I'm "new" in StackOverflow.
I insert a answer with more information about this problem